# Basic string formatting c#

Tags: c#, string, formatting, string-formatting

I am making a simple windows forms application. In my listview i want to display three things; date, time and description. I am now doing it like this:

```
task = date + time + description;
```

(task, date, time, description are all strings).

which give the result:

[image]

But what i want is to make these strings to display below the different categories, something like this:

[image]

How would go about formatting the 3 strings (date,time,desciption) into one (task) so that they display as in picture two?

Comment: Is that a normal `TextBox` control? A `ListView` with 3 columns might be better and easier to format.

Comment: How are you actually displaying the bound data?  It looks like `task` is a single string.  But if you have three separate values and want to display them in column/tabular format, then it would make more sense to create an object containing those three values and bind a `ListView` or `GridView` or something like that to a collection of those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of an expanded example for you.

While you may find a way to concatenate the strings and then space them properly by displaying them in something other than a listview, a listview is going to be your best option.

Your code will look something akin to this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    //Your data
    private string date = "2016-04-04";
    private string time = "20:20";
    private string description = "poop";

    //Declare a list
    public List<object> myList { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        //Instantiate your list
        myList = new List<object>();

        //Make a new object
        var listObject = new
        {
            newDate = date,
            newTime = time,
            newDescription = description
        };

        //Add that object to your list
        myList.Add(listObject);
    }
}
```

And your XAML to display your results:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding newDate}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding newTime}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding newDescription}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating items with `+` will just perform normal string concatenation, which is why you get everything in a single lump.

To do what you ask you have to add a new `ListViewItem` where you specify a string array in the constructor. Each array element represents a column in the `ListView`: `{column 1, column 2, column 3, etc...}`

For example:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {date, time, description}));
```

**MSDN Documentation for the `ListViewItem(string[])` constructor:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `View:Details` from ListView properties to give a grid-style look. When you create a ListItem, it is treated as the data of first column and subsequent SubItems are treated as extra columns for that particular ListItem. Try this example.

```
ListViewItem lvi;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   lvi = new ListViewItem();
   lvi.Text = "first column";
   lvi.SubItems.Add("second column");
   lvi.SubItems.Add("third column");
   listView1.Items.Add(lvi); 
}
```